# Share aspx page having dynamic content from database in google plus

Tags: asp.net, share, meta-tags

I want to share content in google plus via my asp.net website.
I have one page named GooglePlusShare.aspx.
Google Plus takes whatever it finds in og:image and og:description meta tags.
I want to share the content dynamically based on userid which is passed in querystring.
The og:image and og:description meta tags content are being set in the page perfectly but google plus is not rendering it.

Below I've specified the meta tags on that page,they are being set dynamically on page load.

```
<meta id="metaDescription" content="I just entered to win a KitchenAid Kitchen Suite From h.h.gregg - enter now at hhgregg.com/kitchenaid and watch to get a great recipe idea!" property="og:description" name="description">
<meta id="ogImg" content="http://img.youtube.com/vi/http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OT1LFzO8k20/0.jpg" property="og:image">
```

Can any one help me for this.

Thanks in advance,
Priya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Open Graph intro page http://ogp.me/ 4 meta tags are required for every object:

> - og:title - The title of your object as it should appear within the graph, e.g., "The Rock".
> - og:type - The type of your object, e.g., "video.movie". Depending on the type you specify, other properties may also be required.
> - og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph.
> - og:url - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g.,
>     "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/".

Maybe you need to implement all 4 before your page will be recognised?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually Google Plus doesn't share local URL.It works with live URL only.And I was trying to test on local site. But I found the things working once I hosted the site on server.